# Java Class cast exception, Classloader error on using javax xml providers?

Tags: java, jvm, osgi, classloader, apache-felix

I get the following error when I switched from OSGI Equinox to OSGI Karaf runtime.

Earlier the com.sun implementation was working fine, but now I need an apache implementation to run in one environment and com.sun in the older.

I know that OSGI has different class loading mechanism when compared to Java Class loading.

We are providing the javax packages as a part of the rt.jar which contains the Provider interface.

The implementation is coming from com.sun.xml

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider (loaded by org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader@0x0000000100162fd8) (found matching super class javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider loaded by , but needed loader org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader@0x0000000100162fd8)
            at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:43)
            at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:35)
            at javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:126)
```

When I look at the logs, both class loaders seem to have the same ID, then why get a class cast exception?

javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider (loaded by org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$**BundleClassLoader@0x0000000100162fd8**) (found matching super class javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider loaded by , but needed loader org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$**BundleClassLoader@0x0000000100162fd8**)

As of now, I am using a hack to get around this in two different environments

```
private static final String PROVIDER_CXF = "org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl";
private static final String PROVIDER_DEFAULT = "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl";

private String setProvider() {
    log.debug("set default provider");
    System.setProperty(PROVIDER, PROVIDER_DEFAULT);
    try {
        Service.create(new QName(null, ""));
        return PROVIDER_DEFAULT;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug("setting cxf provider");
        System.setProperty(PROVIDER, PROVIDER_CXF);
        return PROVIDER_CXF;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problematic loader is the one with an empty name, referred to in the phrase “ loaded by , but needed …”. The name at the end, after the phrase “but needed loader” is the same, because that’s what what is needed, not what it found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to set `-Dorg.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=com.sun.*`. See https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.module.html#framework.module.parentdelegation. It is possible Equinox provides a common, useful default for boot delegation while Karaf does not.

Comment: for security purposes, I cant boot delegate com.sun